# WPF native controls in Xamarin

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was playing around with Xamarin and WPF after following the BoxViewClock tutorial from the Xamarin website but apart from that one article, which has been duplicated on a number of sites I cannot find any other advanced examples.

Is it currently possible to add/use a WPF custom control to an xamarin forms page? or for that matter a view/user control?

Comment: you can always add custom platform controls to a XF project via custom renderers, but they will only work on that platform

Comment: @Jason Thats fine, is there an example of how to do this for wpf?

Comment: I don't know of a WPF specific example, but the general concept for iOS/Android/UWP should translate fairly directly to WPF.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: I took a look at this example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/view/ For UWP there is a CameraPreviewRenderer but where is the xaml for that control defined?

Comment: there is no XAML

Comment: You can also look at all the WPF renderers that Xamarin has and use them as "study guides": https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WPF

Answer (score 0):

You typically start creating a custom control by deriving from one of Xamarin.Forms controls and you do it in shared .NET Standard library with Xamarin.Forms UI project. As soon as there's behavior which is not feasible within Xamarin.Forms you create a native renderer in a project targeting specific platforms, in our case in WPF project. Thus there're 2 steps for creating custom controls in Xamarin.Forms:

1. Derive from existing Xamarin.Forms controls in Shared project
2. Add extensions to it via platform renderer (or behaviour which is a custom case of renderer) in platform project.

You can find example of creating "ExtendedLabel" control which adds to the standard Xamarin.Forms' Label with capability to change cursor to Hand when mouse hovers over the label in WPF application:

1. Xamarin.Forms control: https://github.com/maxim-saplin/CrossPlatformDiskTest/blob/master/Saplin.CPDT.UICore/Controls/ExtendedLabel.cs
2. WPF platfrom renderer: https://github.com/maxim-saplin/CrossPlatformDiskTest/blob/master/Saplin.CPDT.WPF/ExtendedLabelRenderer.cs - you can ignore the code after "if (label.FormattedText != null &&..." which is a workaround for a bug in Xamarin.WPF and not related to the questions

P.S.: in the repo there's also a renderer for macOS which implements the same behaviour